# Should I install RHEL8 or RHEL7?

Tags: linux, redhat, rhel7, rhel8

I've installed RHEL8 and I'm having some problems with it. There is no Epel-release for RHEL8 and when you install EPEL-7, your package manager becomes broken. I was wondering if RHEL7 is still alive? Is RHEL7 still alive? if so, should I install RHEL7 first then, I wait for people to release RHEL 8 packages?

Comment: I mean. I can fix the broken stuff but should I stay with RHEL8 or switch to RHEL7?

Answer (score 3):

There is an [epel-release for RHEL 8](https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/8/Everything/x86_64/Packages/e/epel-release-8-5.el8.noarch.rpm), which you can install now. But there are very few packages right now, as EPEL is having to be rearchitected significantly for RHEL's new AppStream packaging system. The last I saw on the mailing list is they expected to have most everything done by November 2019.

If your application depends on EPEL packages, you should stay on RHEL 7 for now. It is very much alive; RHEL 7.7 was just released last week, and it still has several years of [support lifetime](https://access.redhat.com/support/policy/updates/errata/) ahead.

Comment: What if i was trying to get a (RHCSA) and (RHCE) Certificate? Should I study on RHEL8 or RHEL7?

Comment: @Cracker That's a different question entirely. This isn't like a normal forum; our format works best with only one question per post. You might make a new post, but keep in mind that we probably won't be able to answer questions asking for opinions. See the [help](https://serverfault.com/help/asking) to learn what makes a good question here and what should be avoided.