# Installing certbot - error - "nothing provides pyparsing"

Tags: redhat, python, lets-encrypt, certbot, pip

I'm trying to set up let's encrypt on my Amazon ec2 RHEL nginx server, via the command `$ sudo yum install certbot-nginx` but it keeps failing:

```
$ sudo yum install certbot-nginx
Last metadata expiration check: 2:58:11 ago on Sat 17 Aug 2019 11:29:45 PM UTC.
Error:
 Problem: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides pyparsing needed by python2-certbot-nginx-0.36.0-1.el7.noarch
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
```

After doing some stumbling around online I installed various python and pip packages (full list is below). Any idea what I could be missing?

Here are my OS details followed by installed python and pip packages...

```
$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
VERSION="8.0 (Ootpa)"
ID="rhel"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VERSION_ID="8.0"
PLATFORM_ID="platform:el8"
PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.0 (Ootpa)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:8.0:GA"
HOME_URL="https://www.redhat.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=8.0
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.0"

platform-python.x86_64                        3.6.8-4.el8_0                               @rhui-rhel-8-baseos-rhui-rpms
platform-python-pip.noarch                    9.0.3-13.el8                                @anaconda
platform-python-setuptools.noarch             39.2.0-4.el8                                @anaconda
policycoreutils-python-utils.noarch           2.8-16.1.el8                                @rhel-8-baseos-rhui-rpms
python2.x86_64                                2.7.15-24.module+el8.0.0.z+3358+99b46920    @rhel-8-appstream-rhui-rpms
python2-libs.x86_64                           2.7.15-24.module+el8.0.0.z+3358+99b46920    @rhel-8-appstream-rhui-rpms
python2-pip.noarch                            9.0.3-13.module+el8.0.0+2961+596d0223       @rhel-8-appstream-rhui-rpms
python2-setuptools.noarch                     39.0.1-11.module+el8.0.0+2961+596d0223      @rhel-8-appstream-rhui-rpms
python3-asn1crypto.noarch                     0.24.0-3.el8                                @anaconda
python3-audit.x86_64                          3.0-0.10.20180831git0047a6c.el8             @anaconda
python3-babel.noarch                          2.5.1-3.el8                                 @koji-override-1
python3-cffi.x86_64                           1.11.5-5.el8                                @anaconda
python3-chardet.noarch                        3.0.4-7.el8                                 @anaconda
python3-configobj.noarch                      5.0.6-11.el8                                @anaconda
python3-cryptography.x86_64                   2.3-2.el8                                   @anaconda
python3-dateutil.noarch                       1:2.6.1-6.el8                               @anaconda
python3-dbus.x86_64                           1.2.4-14.el8                                @anaconda
python3-decorator.noarch                      4.2.1-2.el8                                 @anaconda
python3-dmidecode.x86_64                      3.12.2-13.el8                               @anaconda
python3-dnf.noarch                            4.0.9.2-5.el8                               @anaconda
python3-dnf-plugin-spacewalk.noarch           2.8.5-11.module+el8.0.0.z+3494+e6f475f6     @rhui-rhel-8-appstream-rhui-rpms
python3-dnf-plugins-core.noarch               4.0.2.2-3.el8                               @anaconda
python3-ethtool.x86_64                        0.14-3.el8                                  @anaconda
python3-gobject-base.x86_64                   3.28.3-1.el8                                @anaconda
python3-gpg.x86_64                            1.10.0-6.el8                                @anaconda
python3-hawkey.x86_64                         0.22.5-5.el8_0                              @anaconda
python3-hwdata.noarch                         2.3.6-3.el8                                 @koji-override-1
python3-idna.noarch                           2.5-5.el8                                   @anaconda
python3-iniparse.noarch                       0.4-31.el8                                  @anaconda
python3-inotify.noarch                        0.9.6-13.el8                                @anaconda
python3-jinja2.noarch                         2.10.1-2.el8_0                              @koji-override-1
python3-jsonpatch.noarch                      1.21-2.el8                                  @koji-override-1
python3-jsonpointer.noarch                    1.10-11.el8                                 @koji-override-1
python3-jsonschema.noarch                     2.6.0-4.el8                                 @koji-override-1
python3-jwt.noarch                            1.6.1-2.el8                                 @anaconda
python3-libcomps.x86_64                       0.1.8-13.el8                                @anaconda
python3-libdnf.x86_64                         0.22.5-5.el8_0                              @anaconda
python3-librepo.x86_64                        1.9.2-1.el8                                 @anaconda
python3-libs.x86_64                           3.6.8-4.el8_0                               @rhui-rhel-8-baseos-rhui-rpms
python3-libselinux.x86_64                     2.8-6.el8                                   @anaconda
python3-libsemanage.x86_64                    2.8-5.el8                                   @anaconda
python3-libxml2.x86_64                        2.9.7-5.el8                                 @anaconda
python3-linux-procfs.noarch                   0.6-6.el8                                   @anaconda
python3-magic.noarch                          5.33-8.el8                                  @anaconda
python3-markupsafe.x86_64                     0.23-19.el8                                 @koji-override-1
python3-netifaces.x86_64                      0.10.6-4.el8                                @koji-override-1
python3-newt.x86_64                           0.52.20-9.el8                               @koji-override-1
python3-oauthlib.noarch                       2.1.0-1.el8                                 @anaconda
python3-perf.x86_64                           4.18.0-80.7.2.el8_0                         @rhui-rhel-8-baseos-rhui-rpms
python3-pip.noarch                            9.0.3-13.el8                                @rhel-8-appstream-rhui-rpms
python3-ply.noarch                            3.9-7.el8                                   @anaconda
python3-policycoreutils.noarch                2.8-16.1.el8                                @anaconda
python3-prettytable.noarch                    0.7.2-14.el8                                @koji-override-1
python3-pyOpenSSL.noarch                      18.0.0-1.el8                                @koji-override-1
python3-pycparser.noarch                      2.14-14.el8                                 @anaconda
python3-pyserial.noarch                       3.1.1-8.el8                                 @koji-override-1
python3-pysocks.noarch                        1.6.8-3.el8                                 @anaconda
python3-pytz.noarch                           2017.2-9.el8                                @koji-override-1
python3-pyudev.noarch                         0.21.0-7.el8                                @anaconda
python3-pyyaml.x86_64                         3.12-12.el8                                 @anaconda
python3-requests.noarch                       2.20.0-1.el8                                @anaconda
python3-rhn-check.x86_64                      2.8.16-13.module+el8.0.0.z+3494+e6f475f6    @rhui-rhel-8-appstream-rhui-rpms
python3-rhn-client-tools.x86_64               2.8.16-13.module+el8.0.0.z+3494+e6f475f6    @rhui-rhel-8-appstream-rhui-rpms
python3-rhn-setup.x86_64                      2.8.16-13.module+el8.0.0.z+3494+e6f475f6    @rhui-rhel-8-appstream-rhui-rpms
python3-rhnlib.noarch                         2.8.6-8.module+el8.0.0.z+3494+e6f475f6      @rhui-rhel-8-appstream-rhui-rpms
python3-rpm.x86_64                            4.14.2-10.el8_0                             @rhui-rhel-8-baseos-rhui-rpms
python3-schedutils.x86_64                     0.6-5.el8                                   @anaconda
python3-setools.x86_64                        4.2.0-2.el8                                 @anaconda
python3-setuptools.noarch                     39.2.0-4.el8                                @anaconda
python3-six.noarch                            1.11.0-8.el8                                @anaconda
python3-subscription-manager-rhsm.x86_64      1.23.8-35.el8                               @anaconda
python3-syspurpose.x86_64                     1.23.8-35.el8                               @anaconda
python3-unbound.x86_64                        1.7.3-8.el8                                 @koji-override-1
python3-urllib3.noarch                        1.23-5.el8                                  @anaconda
python36.x86_64                               3.6.8-2.module+el8.0.0+2975+e0f02136        @rhel-8-appstream-rhui-rpms
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You installed RHEL 8, and then added the EPEL repo for RHEL 7. This is not compatible with RHEL 8 and packages from EPEL 7 will not function properly.

You can replace EPEL 7 with EPEL 8 when that becomes available, but it does not currently contain certbot and you still will have to wait for it to be built. It may be a few months before EPEL 8 has most or all packages that are in EPEL 7.

For now you should [deploy your web site on RHEL 7, not RHEL 8](https://serverfault.com/q/978984/126632).

Comment: That probably explains all the trouble I've been having with setting this server up. Unfortunately RHEL 8 is the only one Amazon has on the free tier. Guess I'll try their free-tier Ubuntu 18

Comment: @MikeWillis Eh? You should still be able to use [RHEL 7](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00KWBZVK6). It shows as being on the free tier. You can also use CentOS.

Comment: I couldn't find either! I must be looking in the wrong spot or something. Side question, would you recommend CentOS over RHEL 7?

Comment: @MikeWillis On AWS there's not very much reason to use RHEL over CentOS, unless you are deploying a proprietary app that requires RHEL and the vendor specifically says they won't support it on CentOS. If you're just deploying a web site, there is no significant difference and no compelling reason to choose one over the other.

Comment: Got it - thanks! I found various CentOS and RHEL 7 installs under the community section